# Getting wrong file name while pattern matching in makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, build

The directory structure of my project is something like this:

```
|-build
|-src
   |-lib
      |-libfile1.hpp
      |-libfile1.cpp
      |-libfile2.hpp
      |-libfile2.cpp
      |-libfile3.hpp 
      |-Makefile(lib)
   |-examples
      |-pingpong
          |-main.cpp
          |-ping.cpp
          |-ping.hpp
          |-Makefile(ping)
```

My goal is to have many examples in the examples folder which all use the libfiles but are independent of each other. Hence I wanted to use separate makefiles in each of the example folders to link to objects of libfiles.

To that goal, here's makefile(lib):

```
SRC = .
BLD = ../../build

SOURCE = $(wildcard $(SRC)/*.cpp)
INCLUDE = $(wildcard $(SRC)/*.hpp)
OBJECT = $(patsubst %,$(BLD)/%, $(notdir $(SOURCE:.cpp=.o)))

CC = g++

#flags went here, removed for brevity

all: $(OBJECT)

$(BLD)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.cpp $(SRC)/%.hpp
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    $(RM) -r $(BLD)
```

And here's makefile(ping), where I try to build local objects and pass the library object build pattern to makefile(lib):

```
TARGET = mainpingpong.out

SRC = ../../actorlib
BLD = ../../../build

LIBSOURCE = $(wildcard $(SRC)/*.cpp)
LIBINCLUDE = $(wildcard $(SRC)/*.hpp)
LIBOBJECT = $(patsubst %,$(BLD)/%, $(notdir $(LIBSOURCE:.cpp=.o)))
LOCSOURCE =  $(wildcard *.cpp)
LOCINCLUDE = $(wildcard *.hpp)
LOCOBJECT = $(patsubst %,$(BLD)/%, $(notdir $(LOCSOURCE:.cpp=.o)))

CC = g++
$(TARGET) : $(LIBOBJECT) $(LOCOBJECT)
    $(CC)-o $@ $^

$(LOCOBJECT): $(LOCSOURCE) $(LOCINCLUDE)
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@

$(LIBOBJECT): $(LIBSOURCE) $(LIBINCLUDE)
    cd $(SRC) && $(MAKE)

.PHONY: clean

clean :
    cd $(SRC) && $(MAKE) clean
```

The error occurs in my local file matching, where it associates both main.o and ping.o with main.cpp (everything else works fine):

```
mkdir -p ../../../build/
g++ -c main.cpp -o ../../../build/main.o

mkdir -p ../../../build/
g++ -c main.cpp -o ../../../build/ping.o
```

How do I correctly do what I'm trying to do? Should I have a different rule or target? Or is there a correct way to get the filename from the variable?

I want the .o files to end up in the same place but the executable to stay in the examples directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
$(LOCOBJECT): $(LOCSOURCE) $(LOCINCLUDE)
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@
```

`LOCSOURCE` contains `main.cpp ping.cpp`, so this rule makes *both* source files prerequisites of *each* target. Whether Make is trying to build `main.o` or `ping.o`, the prerequisite list is the same: `main.cpp ping.cpp ping.hpp`. So the automatic variable `$<` always expands to `main.cpp` (since that is the first filename in the list).

One way to solve this is by means of a [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern):

```
$(LOCOBJECT): $(BLD)/%.o: %.cpp $(LOCINCLUDE)
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@
```

This is still imperfect, in that all local header files are prerequisites of each object from a local source. If you have a `paddle.cpp` and you modify `ping.hpp`, Make will rebuild `paddle.o`, even if paddle.cpp does not depend on `ping.hpp` in any way. This is not a serious problem, it simply means that Make will do some extra work, rebuilding things when there is no reason to. If you want to solve it, you can either write the dependencies into the makefile by hand, or use a more sophisticated method like [automatic dependency generation](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation).

Comment: Thanks, this worked, however I replaced $(BLD)/%: with $(BLD)/%.o, otherwise I got the error "make: *** No rule to make target 'ping.o.cpp', needed by '../../../build/ping.o'.  Stop."